# Share an Image on the company Facebook profile

Tags: android, facebook

I have implemented a Facebook feature in my application when user posts a product to sell, I give an option to share that product on his facebook profile as well.

In order to advertise my app, I would like to share that product on the company Facebook profile as well. How is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean "the company"?

Comment: Custom Facebook Profile which I made it. You could post something on your Facebook, but I wonder how could I get user post on my custom Facebook profile?

Comment: First of all, I hope you did not create a user profile for your company (that would not be allowed) – you should use a Facebook page for that. // Sharing/posting onto a page does not seem possible any more using the dialogs Facebook provides (only onto pages the user is an admin of) – so you would need to make that post via API, which means users will have to login to your app and give it permission to post.

Comment: @CBroe, Firs user has to login to my application in order to post a product to sell. Could you please share an example how to use the Facebook API to post a Facebook page?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/page/feed#publish